# I am working on checkbox filter ,i am not getting to handle multiple values of checkbox in query where cause

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am setting checked values in array  and passing that array to model function, I am not getting how to handle checkbox values in where clause of query

my view page:

```
<form id="filterform" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/forFilter?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&name=<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>">">
   <?php foreach ($supplier as $menu1) { ?>
     <div class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox"  name="state[]" id="" value="<?php echo $menu1->state_name; ?>" class="custm-position">
       <label><?php echo $menu1->state_name; ?></label>
     </div>
   <?php } ?>
 </form>
```

my controller code:

```
 public function forFilter(){
      $id = $_GET["id"];
      $total_row = $this->productdisplay_model->filter_count($id,$state_id);
      $this->applyFilter($state_id);
    }

    public function applyFilter($state_id){
        $data['ListMenuLevel1'] = $this->Categories_model->listsector1();
        $data['supplier'] = $this->supplier_select_model->select_supplier();
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/welcome/applyFilter";
        $total_row = $this->productdisplay_model->filter_count($this->session->userdata('forfilter_id'),$state_id);
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
        $config['per_page'] = 20;
        //$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        //$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        //$config['reuse_query_string'] = FALSE;
        $config['num_links'] = 1;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        /* if($this->uri->segment(3)){
          $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
          }
          else{
          $page = 1;
          } */
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 1);
        //$offset = $config['per_page']*$page;
        $offset = (($config['per_page']) * ($page - 1));
        $limit = $config['per_page'];

       $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);
        $data['sub3products'] = $this->productdisplay_model->filter_result($this->session->userdata('sub3_id'),$limit, $offset,$state_id);
        $this->load->view('productdetails', $data);
    }
```

my model:

```
public function filter_count($id,$state_id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('sub3_category');
        $this->db->where('sub2_categoryid_fk', $id);
        $this->db->order_by("sub3_category.sub2_categoryid_fk ");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return  $query->num_rows();
    }

     public function filter_result($id,$limit, $offset,$state_id){
         $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('sub3_category');
        $this->db->where('sub2_categoryid_fk', $id);
        $this->db->order_by("sub3_category.sub2_categoryid_fk ");
        $this->db->join('supplier_otherdetails', 'sub3_category.supplier_id_fk=supplier_otherdetails.sup_id', 'left outer');
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

my jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filterform").on("change", "input:checkbox", function(){
        $("#filterform").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use `where_in` instead of `where` for `$id`. Where `$id` is an `array()`

Comment: Show us code of select_supplier() method in your model file.

Comment: @Gaurav i used where_in , filter is happening but checkbox is not showing checked state because page is reloading,please i need solution for this

Comment: @Rahul Please pass state id into the view from `apply_filter` function like this: `$data['state_ids'] = $state_id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated view page:**

```
<form id="filterform" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/forFilter?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&name=<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>">">
   <?php foreach ($supplier as $menu1) { ?>
     <div class="checkbox">
       <?php $checked = (in_array($menu1->state_name, $state_ids) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?>
       <input type="checkbox"  name="state[]" id="" value="<?php echo $menu1->state_name; ?>" class="custm-position" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
       <label><?php echo $menu1->state_name; ?></label>
     </div>
   <?php } ?>
 </form>
```

**updated controller code:**

```
public function forFilter(){
    $id = $this->input->get('id', true);
    $state_id= $this->input->post('state', true);
    $total_row = $this->productdisplay_model->filter_count($id,$state_id);
    $this->applyFilter($state_id);
}

public function applyFilter($state_id){
    $data['ListMenuLevel1'] = $this->Categories_model->listsector1();
    $data['supplier'] = $this->supplier_select_model->select_supplier();
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/welcome/applyFilter";
    $total_row = $this->productdisplay_model->filter_count($this->session->userdata('forfilter_id'),$state_id);
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
    $config['per_page'] = 20;
    //$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    //$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    //$config['reuse_query_string'] = FALSE;
    $config['num_links'] = 1;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    /* if($this->uri->segment(3)){
      $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
      }
      else{
      $page = 1;
      } */
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 1);
    //$offset = $config['per_page']*$page;
    $offset = (($config['per_page']) * ($page - 1));
    $limit = $config['per_page'];

    $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);
    $data['sub3products'] = $this->productdisplay_model->filter_result($this->session->userdata('sub3_id'),$limit, $offset,$state_id);

    $data['state_ids'] = $state_id; //new line added

    $this->load->view('productdetails', $data);
}
```

Comment: i should enable one checkbox checked at a time , in above code what changes i should make

Comment: pass `$data['state_ids']` to the view check controller on second last line.

Comment: Can you show your controller snapshot. function should be like this `public function applyFilter($state_id){` and `$this->applyFilter($state_id);`

Comment: on your controller from where did you getting `$state_id`.

Comment: from view in forFilter() function $state_id = $this->input->post('state');

Comment: same output i am getting nochange

Comment: if i do this  
pass $data['state_ids'] to the view check controller on second last line. i will  get error like undefined variable links and sub3products because we didnt pass $data instead we passed $data['state_ids'] to view

Comment: what is your view name? in which view you have put form?

Comment: same view, productdetails

Comment: Then you have variable links `error` which is not related to $data['state_ids']`. And why are you exploding links? Use as string in view.

Comment: like this your are telling,in last line of controller
        $this->load->view('productdetails',$data, $state_id);

Comment: No, when you load view and pass third param it means you want view as string. Call only `$this->load->view('productdetails',$data);`. Read Codeigniter documentation  carefully.

Comment: sorry , i am not getting you

Comment: in last four lines of controller code ,what changes i should make  $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);
    $data['sub3products'] = $this->productdisplay_model->filter_result($this->session->userdata('sub3_id'),$limit, $offset,$state_id);

    $data['state_ids'] = $state_id; //new line added

    $this->load->view('productdetails', $data);

Comment: do not pass third variable in load view. Just refer my code which i have updated previously.  [Read this](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html?highlight=view)

Comment: i executed your previously updated code but also i'm getting same output as first i use to get,here everything is working fine but  
i should enable one checkbox checked at a time

Comment: because in your jquery script you are submitting form on change. So when you clicked on checkbox it will submitted form. So instead of submitting form by jquery use submit button in the form.

Comment: but usually there will be no submit buttons for checkbox filter,i am referring flipkart website for filter

Comment: then submit form by ajax.